# Basic jQuery Calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator

I'm working on a jQuery calculator. Everything was working great until a few minutes ago, and now nothing will fire. Did I accidentally put a bad character in the code on accident? I've scanned up and down it a few times, but couldn't find the source. Any help would be appreciated!

Head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-calc.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("ready");
 $('#salary, #transcribing-hours, #cost-of-assistant').keydown(function(e){
    var key = e.which;
    if (key != 8 && key != 9 && key != 37 && key != 38 && key != 39 && key != 40 && key != 46 && key != 110 && key != 190 && key != 13){
        if (key < 48){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (key > 57 && key < 96){
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        else if (key > 105) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
 });
});

$('#salary').on('input', function() {
    var salary = $('#salary').val();
    var costofassist = $('#cost-of-assistant').val();
    var total = salary / (52 * 40);
    var roundtotal = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;

    $('#hourly-pay-total').text(roundtotal);

});

$('#transcribing-hours').on('input', function() {
    var hoursday = $('#transcribing-hours').val();
    var hoursweek = hoursday * 5;
    var hoursmonth = hoursweek * 4.3;
    var hoursyear = hoursweek * 52;

    $('#transcribing-year').text(Math.round(hoursyear * 100) / 100);
    $('#transcribing-month').text(Math.round(hoursmonth * 100) / 100);
    $('#transcribing-week').text(Math.round(hoursweek * 100) / 100);

    var roundtotal = $('#hourly-pay-total').text();
    var costwithoutyear = (hoursweek * roundtotal) * 52;
    var costwithoutmonth = (hoursweek * roundtotal) * 4.3;
    var costwithoutweek = hoursweek * roundtotal;

    $('#cost-without-year').text(Math.round(costwithoutyear * 100) / 100);
    $('#cost-without-month').text(Math.round(costwithoutmonth * 100) / 100);
    $('#cost-without-week').text(Math.round(costwithoutweek * 100) / 100);

});

$('#cost-of-assistant').on('input', function() {
    var costofassist = $('#cost-of-assistant').val();
    var costwithoutyear = $('#cost-without-year').text();
    var annualsavings = costwithoutyear - costofassist;
    var monthlysavings = annualsavings / 12;
    var weeklysavings = annualsavings / 52;
    var dailysavings = annualsavings / 260;

    $('#annual-savings').text((Math.round(annualsavings * 100) / 100);
    $('#monthly-savings').text(Math.round(monthlysavings * 100) / 100);
    $('#weekly-savings').text(Math.round(weeklysavings * 100) / 100);
    $('#daily-savings').text(Math.round(dailysavings * 100) / 100);
});
```

Comment: FYI: Best way to trace any problem in javascript is open up page in google chtome and press `F12` for development mode. It'll show you the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line 59 of your jQuery-code is one opening bracket too much.

```
 $('#annual-savings').text((Math.round(annualsavings * 100) / 100);
```

Should be:

```
 $('#annual-savings').text(Math.round(annualsavings * 100) / 100);
```

Hint: If you using e.g. Firefox or Safari, you have a javascript-console, which can detect such syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use the firebug plugin and I am quite pleased with it.In the console tab  it would show you syntax errors like the one spotted by   ok. I use mozilla but I am pretty sure Chrome supports it as well. You should give it a try.